# Corresponding natural transformations to representable functors

Tags: solution-verification, category-theory

This is a question concerning exercise 2.1.i of Emily Riehl's book *Category Theory in Context*.

> For the functors $0: \mathbf{1} \rightarrow \mathbf{2}$, $1: \mathbf{1} \rightarrow \mathbf{2}$, and  $!: \mathbf{2} \rightarrow \mathbf{1}$, between the categories $\mathbf{1}$ and $\mathbf{2}$, describe the corresponding natural transformations between the covariant functors $Cat \rightrightarrows Set$ represented by the categories $\mathbf{1}$ and $\mathbf{2}$.

I am not sure if what is meant by *corresponding natural transformations*. I think I have found, for example, a natural transformation $Cat(\mathbf{2}, - ) \Rightarrow Cat(\mathbf{1},-)$ defined by sending an element of $Cat(\mathbf{2},C)$, which is a functor from $\mathbf{2}$ to a small category $C$, which is the same as picking an arrow in $C$, to the domain of this arrow (interpreted as a functor $\mathbf{1} \rightarrow C$). This should maybe correspond to the first functor? And similarly picking the codomain corresponds to the second one. Is this what is meant in this exercise?

Comment: "Corresponding" means that a functor $F : C \to D$ induces a natural transformation between the representable functors $\text{Cat}(D, -)$ and $\text{Cat}(C, -)$ via precomposition and Riehl wants you to compute what that natural transformation is.

Comment: A morphism $f \colon A \to B$ in a category $\mathcal C$ induces a natural transformation $\mathcal C(f,\_) \colon \mathcal C(B,\_) \to \mathcal C(A,\_)$ whose component at $X \in \mathcal C$ is the function $\mathcal C(f,X) \colon \mathcal C(B,X) \to \mathcal C(A,X)$ defined by $g \mapsto fg$.

Comment: Thank you, now I got it!